# Cooling circuit board for troubleshooting

Tags: pcb, testing, troubleshooting, cooling, production-testing

I'm trying to troubleshoot an LCD TV. It turns off at random intervals I'm guessing as it heats up with use. I want to determine which PCB is failing with heat, and then even isolate the area on the failing PCB. Is there an easy way to cool the PCB temporarily. A small fan is one idea. Can I spray the board with something to cool it down temporarily? I thought I've heard of that.
PS. I've tested all caps and they are all within spec. Also don't visibly see cold solder joints.

Comment: Don't count those caps as good just yet.  If you have the system in a failing state, use the freeze spray to cool them down one by one until the issue goes away.  LCD monitors are prone to this type of failure.  You can also use a heat gun to target areas of the PCB to speed up the failure.

Comment: canned air duster can be used to cool down components ... it does not have to be "freeze spray" specifically ... if you turn the duster can upside down, then it sprays the liquid, which sucks up a lot of heat as it evaporates

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the is an aerosol spray made for this purpose. Google “circuit chiller” or search your favorite distributor like Digikey or Mouser under the chemicals category.

Comment: I hear you can also use compressed air from the hardware store. It cools down as it expands.

Comment: the canned "air" is the stame stuff as in the chill cans,  just hold the "air" can upside-down so that it squirts liquid

Answer (score 0):

What you need is freezer spray...

you get it at every better shop for electronics stuff like

https://www.conrad.com/p/toolcraft-tc-kc400c-tc-kc400c-freezer-spray-non-flammable-400-ml-887253